# Best practice for spring-boot REST response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I am new to `spring` and I am working on a fairly simple REST API.

I am getting a request without any data, and I need to send back some info. What would be the better way of doing so?

**Entity**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ping", consumes = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> checkServerStatus() throws Exception {

    Ping ping = new Ping();
    ping.setStatus("alive");
    ping.setVersion("v1");

    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(ping);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Service is not reachable at the moment", e);
    }
}
```

OR

**Response**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ping2", consumes = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> checkServerStatus2() throws Exception {

    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new PingResponse("alive", "v1"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Service is not reachable at the moment", e);
    }
}
```

I figured no need to show `PingResponse` and `Ping`. They are typical `get/set` classes.

If both ways aren't ideal then maybe there is a better way of doing so?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is that you have your object in the try block or not. And that `PingResponse` **could be** an immutable object (no setters).

Entity/Response? they are both **Objects**.

So there is no difference worth taking notice in your provided code examples.

Comment: You are correct, didn't notice while I was writing it.

Answer (score 1):

From your example it seems that, you just need to let the caller know that your service is up. Why are you creating an object? You can just notify the caller.

```
return new ResponseEntity<>("success", HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: I have other variables included in that response (env, name, etc.) I just didn't include them because they are fixed and not relevant. Thanks for the reply, I will probably go with option #1.

Answer (score -1):

you can just return the object from back end

```
@GetMapping("/ping")   
public Ping  checkServerStatus(){   
    Ping ping = new Ping();    
    ping.setStatus("alive");    
    ping.setVersion("v1");   
        return ping;   
}
```